# How to use semicolon(;) as a part of command in shell script

Tags: makefile, sh

I am trying run a tool via gnumake.

```
$(cksumS19) :
$(MY_TOOL_PATH)/toolname $(cksumS19) /CS14:@0x1FFFA;0x500000-0x70FFEF
```

semicolon ; in the above command is treated as command separator and throwing command not found error for string (0x500000-0x70FFEF). 
Can anybody help me please?

I have tried appending $1 to the above command but script became unresponsive.
I have tried to run this in batch script and was successful, but this batch file is not invoked during make.

Comment: wrap argument into quotes: "/CS14:@0x1FFFA;0x500000-0x70FFEF"

Comment: No, adding quotes is not working. Make does not run this target at all, simply moves to next target.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use subshells `$()`? Especially `MY_TOOL_PATH` looks like a variable to me, so you should use `"$MY_TOOL_PATH"`. And the first `$(cksumS19)` should probably be just `cksumS19`.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny :
Update: Using double quotes worked!
I earlier did a rookie mistake of keeping last generated cksumS19 file from the source folder making the gnumake.exe not-run the changed script. After I deleted and run with double quotes, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Socowi : MY_TOOL_PATH represents path string where tool "toolname.exe" lies. S-record .s19 file represented by cksumS19. toolname.exe takes .s19 file as input for processing. Thank you for your input too.

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with makefiles, it's _all_ about the shell.  The real question is, how to escape `;` from the shell.  It definitely _is_ a `bash` question (or anyway a `sh` question).  Just because it's on Windows doesn't mean it's not related to POSIX shell: there are a lot of ways (including being invoked by make) to run a POSIX shell on Windows.

Comment: Is your recipe indented? What you have posted now is a target with an empty recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap argument with quotes: "/CS14:@0x1FFFA;0x500000-0x70FFEF"